# I can pass dictionary as action parameter but can't pass it inside complex object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, postman

I want to pass `IDictionary<string, List<string>>` inside a DTO complex object into a ASP.NET 5 Api action using Postman.

First i tried to pass solo `IDictionary<string, List<string>>` which is working. Here is how i do it:

I use this request body:

```
{
    "Key1": [
        "Val1",
        "Val1"
    ],
    "Key2": [
        "Val1",
        "Val1"
    ]
}
```

And it works well, when I pass it like this to action:

```
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public IActionResult EditTags(int id, [FromBody] IDictionary<string, List<string>> tags)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

It works:
[image]

The problem is I need to wrap wthis dictionary inside complex object like this:

```
    public class DTO
    {
        public string SomeValue{ get; set; }

        IDictionary<string, List<string>> Tags{ get; set; }
     }
```

And take this in as a parameter to action:

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult EditTags(int id, [FromBody] DTO model)
    {
        //Do something with the model here
        return Ok();
    }
```

But the model.tags is null.

I use this request body:

```
{
    "SomeValue": "Value",
    "Tags": {
        "Key1": [
            "Val1",
            "Val1"
        ],
        "Key2": [
            "Val1",
            "Val1"
        ]
    }
}
```

But the model.Tags is null:

[image: model.Tags is null]

Comment: Do not know the answer to your question, but maybe try NewtonSoft.JSON instead of build in System.Text.Json? https://www.ryadel.com/en/use-json-net-instead-of-system-text-json-in-asp-net-core-3-mvc-projects/

Comment: Add `public` access modifier for `Tags` in your class.

Comment: Yes it helped, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to mark my `Tags` property as public at first place:

```
public IDictionary<string, List<string>> Tags{ get; set; }
```

if it still doesn't work, I think you need to use the `JsonExtensionData` attribute in this case. Take a look at [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeExtensionData.htm) also for more details.